# No openjdk development package found, please install JDK package,

Tags: java, javac

I have my java installed and linked.
Still when I run another config it shows no openjdk development package found. Although I have java installed and linked using a pre built release

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/perf-6.4.0$ make -C tools/perf/
make: Entering directory '/home/pegasus/Documents/perf-6.4.0/tools/perf'
  BUILD:   Doing 'make -j16' parallel build
Makefile.config:1105: No openjdk development package found, please install JDK package, e.g. openjdk-8-jdk, java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

  INSTALL libsubcmd_headers
  INSTALL libapi_headers
  INSTALL libperf_headers
  INSTALL libsymbol_headers
  GEN     python/perf.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  INSTALL libbpf_headers
  CC      scripts/python/Perf-Trace-Util/Context.o
In file included from /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/Python.h:44,
                 from scripts/python/Perf-Trace-Util/Context.c:14:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/object.h: In function ‘Py_SIZE’:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/object.h:233:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
  233 |     PyVarObject *var_ob = _PyVarObject_CAST(ob);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/Python.h:53:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/longintrepr.h: In function ‘_PyLong_CompactValue’:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/longintrepr.h:121:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
  121 |     Py_ssize_t sign = 1 - (op->long_value.lv_tag & _PyLong_SIGN_MASK);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
  CC      util/scripting-engines/trace-event-python.o
In file included from /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/Python.h:44,
                 from util/scripting-engines/trace-event-python.c:22:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/object.h: In function ‘Py_SIZE’:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/object.h:233:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
  233 |     PyVarObject *var_ob = _PyVarObject_CAST(ob);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
In file included from /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/Python.h:53:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/longintrepr.h: In function ‘_PyLong_CompactValue’:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/longintrepr.h:121:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
  121 |     Py_ssize_t sign = 1 - (op->long_value.lv_tag & _PyLong_SIGN_MASK);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
make[5]: *** [/home/pegasus/Documents/perf-6.4.0/tools/build/Makefile.build:98: scripts/python/Perf-Trace-Util/Context.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [/home/pegasus/Documents/perf-6.4.0/tools/build/Makefile.build:140: python/Perf-Trace-Util] Error 2
make[3]: *** [/home/pegasus/Documents/perf-6.4.0/tools/build/Makefile.build:140: scripts] Error 2
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
^Cmake[5]: *** [/home/pegasus/Documents/perf-6.4.0/tools/build/Makefile.build:98: util/scripting-engines/trace-event-python.o] Interrupt
make[4]: *** [/home/pegasus/Documents/perf-6.4.0/tools/build/Makefile.build:140: scripting-engines] Interrupt
interrupted
make[3]: *** [/home/pegasus/Documents/perf-6.4.0/tools/build/Makefile.build:140: util] Interrupt
make[2]: *** [Makefile.perf:675: perf-in.o] Interrupt
make[2]: *** [Makefile.perf:650: python/perf.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so] Interrupt
make[1]: *** [Makefile.perf:235: sub-make] Interrupt
make: *** [Makefile:70: all] Interrupt
```

Despite me having java and javac 21. Why am I seeing this error?
How can I fix it?

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/perf-6.4.0$ java --version
openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-58)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-58, mixed mode, sharing)
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/perf-6.4.0$ javac --version
javac 21.0.2
```

Comment: Maybe you need to install `openjdk-8-source`

Comment: Just to be clear:  You're interested in working around the warning about the missing jdk but not the compilation errors which look unreleated?

Comment: I think the error originated from not finding openjdk

Comment: I uninstalled all openjdk. Then did fresh installation of default-jdk. It solved the issue.